# Sleep method doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, I have a chess board application. The application has 64 panels within a groupbox. These panels are identified with the expression CHessBoardPanels{x,y). I am using this to change the background color of the panels. I want a small delay in between where the chessPanel.BackGround changes to red and when the panels turn back to white.(approximately 1 to 2 second delay)
I have tried the Sleep function but it basically locks the application up till the task have been complete

Here is the code which I have tried:

```
for (int Row = 7; Row > 3; --Row)
{
    chessBoardPanels[ Column ,Row].BackColor = Color.Red;
    ++Column;
    //Add text to Moves TextBox
    MovesText.AppendFormat("WhtB {0} {1}{2}", ColumnText, RowText, Environment.NewLine);
    MovesTxt.Text = MovesText.ToString();
    ++ColumnText;
    --RowText;
}

//Start White Horizonal Drill
Column = 0;
Thread.Sleep(5000);             //This does not delay proerperly
for (int Row = 7; Row > 4; --Row)
{
    chessBoardPanels[Column, Row].BackColor = Color.White;
    ++Column;
    //Add text to Moves TextBox
    MovesText.AppendFormat("WhtB {0} {1}{2}", ColumnText, RowText, Environment.NewLine);
    MovesTxt.Text = MovesText.ToString();
    ++ColumnText;
    --RowText;
}
```

I am using .Net framework 4.0 because Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support 4.5

Comment: Please fix your code's formatting and indentaion. Right now it is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: what do you mean by 'properly'? The Sleep method is *supposed* to lock your application up while it runs, so if it's doing that, it's working 'properly'...

Comment: You have told the thread to sleep, and your question is: why is it sleeping?

Comment: I'm not real sure exactly what you meant by the formatting is unreadable....

Comment: What I actually want the first loop to do is change the background of the ChessBoardPanels...then wait a few seconds..then change them back to white.  I have been stuck on this since yesterday morning

Comment: Real code doesn't Sleep(). Reserve that method for demos and mock-ups.

Comment: Just put your code into another Thread and your main Thread doesnt freeze. And than use methodinvoker if needed [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/methodinfo-invoke)

Answer (score 5):

That's what Sleep does, it pauses the thread.

What you need is to use a `Timer` control, and create a queue with color changes, and let the timer control call an event handler periodically, like so:

(in your Form class):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

(in your Form's constructor):

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Interval = 500; // every 1/2 second
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();
```

Then your event handler would do something like this:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read a queue, that contains timings
    var nextItem = PeekAtQueue();
    if ((nextItem != null) && (nextItem.WhenToChangeColor <= DateTime.Now))
    {
        var item = TakeFromQueue(); // as opposed to just peeking
        ChangeColor(item);
    }
}
```

What does this do? (Of course this code is not 100% complete, you'll have to add the queue-accessing methods yourself, it depends on what you want/can use)

- Seeing that Sleep() freezes your application temporarily, you need a
  solution that allows you to still interact with your form, while
  still having a delay and doing something after that delay.
- So you
  need to use a timer to execute something at a later date. The timer
  in this example gets executed every 1/2 second but you can use any
  interval you choose.
- Point is, because of this timer and this
  configuration, a certain method -- the event handler -- is executed
  every 1/2 second, or the interval of your choice.
- So what you can
  then do is, when you want a certain color change to happen later, to
  queue an object that describes the color change, for instance `{E5, "red", today at 04:20:30 PM}`.
- The event handler executed by the
  timer peeks every time to see if there is something in the queue, and
  to have a look at what it is. It checks whether the "moment to change
  the color", as described in the queued object, is now or has already
  passed. If so, it changes the color. If not, it leaves the item at
  the top of the queue, and the next time the event handler gets
  executed again (1/2 second later), it will perform the same check
  again.
- Once a color change is done, the object is taken off the
  queue.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are other types of timers but that this is using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: That is what you get if you use the above code in a Form, as specified, yes.

Comment: Ok but the PeekAtQueue method doesn't exist

Comment: @RoyDictus: I thought it might be educational to explain there are other classes in the framework called "Timer" that have other uses. I guess I can just link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547980/which-c-sharp-timer from here though. :)

Comment: @user3501478: You have to write that yourself, yes, I'm not going to do all your work :) The answer gives you an idea how to solve your problem while leaving the stuff that is specific to your application to you. Notice that the answer also doesn't tell you which queue class to use or how to initialize it...

Comment: Honestly I am trying just make the delay hap-pen.  I have searched for 2 days trying to get past a small problem with a delay.  Didn't ask for someone to do all the work...But what good does a answer which doesn't really explain what is happening or that does nothing but create error do...I mean Im trying to learn here...The examples online are just to complicated or I just don't understand

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were a developer. I'll add some more explanations to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class instead.  That should allow you to delay your application without locking the thread.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried the Sleep function but it basically locks the application
>   up till the task have been complete

You need to move the logic of your application our of the main (or UI) thread. Your application will "freeze" if you call a `Thread.Sleep` in the main (UI) thread as the Windows event-handling loop is blocked.

Things you can use:

- New Thread, Task, Background worker to execute logic of the game
- Timers
- Update the GUI from another thread

Answer (score 0):

Sleep will lock the current thread, meaning if it's the main UI thread then no user input will be processed - and ideally you should set an hourglass cursor at that point.

To do what you want I think you need to start a background timer and then set the colours on the callback, then cancel the timer.

While the timer is ticking down the main UI will still be responsive.
You might also find that over 1 second delay will feel like too long a delay for users, but the timer period is in milliseconds so you can define a shorter delay.

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000)).Wait();
```

Comment: But the Run method doesn't exist