# Using a timer to call a method of a form control C#, threading issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I am building a custom control for a few of my forms which is an "indictor light"; an edit control that just changed color.

I would like to set a timer and see what the "light" looks like when it switches from state to state.

I have been reviewing this link [C# Elapsed Timer MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Though this does not work for me. I think the issue has to do with the `Timer` executing on another Thread meaning I cannot interact with the `this` (this.editControl.[...]) within the `OnTimedEvent` method.

Is there a simple Timer I could use to just call a method of a forms controls every second or so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which C# Timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547980/which-c-sharp-timer)

Comment: Not being able to access ("interact with") `this` is related to scope of the callback, not threading - but you're using the wrong timer for general Winforms use. In the linked example the callback is static so there is no "this". If you were to remove the `static` keyword from the callback method it would "work" (as in compile), but likely fail at runtime due to cross-threading UI access.

Comment: Yeah, thats what it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the Timer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) (the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class). You can find it in the Toolbox when on a designer canvas.

Set the `Interval` property to 1000 (1 second) and make sure its `Enabled`. The `Tick` event fires at every interval and is raised in the UI thread.

Comment: While this is true, I *suspect* the OP is getting a compiler error on "this" due to using `static` on the callback method as shown in the example linked.

Comment: You are probably correct. I just went straight for an easier answer for the OP.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead knew what I needed.